# Apache closes connection too early

Tags: apache-2.2, haproxy, curl

I am trying to debug an issue we are having with some embedded devices when they are downloading Firmware over-the-air and closing connections too early, failing to get all data.

I tried downloading the file with curl and wget but it gets downloaded without problems and the checksums match.

The only "hint" that I could find is when I run curl with the verbose option (-v). I created a file with dummy content, only containing the word dummy many times over.

When I run `curl -v http://myserver/dummy.txt` I get this response:

`dummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummClosing connection #0
ydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummy`

Why is there the "Closing connection #0" before the end of data?

The apache version is 2.2, we also have HAProxy in front of it, but I get the same "issue" if I curl locally on the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: what you see is only a display artefact on your terminal and no indication of any issue with either your webserver or HAproxy closing connections too early.

---

I think that reeks of the counter intuitive effects of output buffering.

Default behaviour of Linux glibc is to do **line buffering** when standard output is sent to a TTY. That will buffer the output and only display a block of data on your terminal when either:

- an end-of-line is observed
- the output buffer is full
- the program terminates.

It wouldn't surprise me if the "Closing connection" message  is sent to **standard error  which gets displayed immediately** but the last bit of content from your URL only comes out of the buffer when curl terminates.

You'll probably see a more intuitive and sequential result when you change the buffering with [`stdbuff`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) and make the error and output modes unbuffered:

```
stdbuf -o0 -e0 curl -v http://myserver/dummy.txt
```

But also when you change your data to include more new-lines:

```
dummy
dummy
dummy
...
```

Comment: Thank you HBruijn, it is exactly as you described. stdbuf or a newline character displays the flow correctly